# present two view controllers from different location in the view hierarchy, so one view can be on top whenever an interruption occurs?

Tags: ios, view, interruption

I have an application where the root view controller is an UITabBarController that have several tabs controllers. This tabs controllers could presents others view controllers as the User modify some elements. When a certain notification occurs, I would like to present a view on Top of all others possible views even if some others controllers as already presented one.

When no interruption :

```
    (UITabController)
           |
           |
           |
      ---------------
     |       |       |
    Ctrl1  Ctrl2   Ctrl3
     |
     |
Presented ctrl (TopView)
```

I tried to do this but it fails :

When an interruption :

```
    (UITabController)----->(Presented Interruption View --> not visible)
           |
           |
           |
      ---------------
     |       |       |
    Ctrl1  Ctrl2   Ctrl3
     |
     |
Presented ctrl (TopView)
```

What is the good way to manage a view that can be presented wherever in the view hierarchy and whenever in time ?

Comment: If each tab is contained in a UINavigationController, you could present a modal view controller and save yourself the headache of managing a view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to handle your situation is to present a view controller modally. It then does not affect the rest of your view hierarchy.

In your case, a `UINavigationController` would make the presentation instead of the `UITabBarController`.

Make a separate view controller and present it modally during interruptions.

```
[ yourViewController presentViewController : viewControllerForInterruption animated : YES completion : ^{ // completion block 
 } ];
```

You can resume by using the corresponding dismiss method.

```
[ viewControllerForInterruption dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{ // completion block
 } ];
```

Note: These are methods for iOS 6.

Comment: I tried to do this in a sample project. The problem is that the UITabController can not present a view controller if one of its children has already presented one.

Comment: I've set up a tab bar controller project and I'm able to present another UINavigationController on top of a UINavigationController that I just presented. I'm not sure I understand what you are doing. Do you have a top view that is on top of the view containing the tab bar? Or is your top view a view contained by a navigation controller and accessible through the tab bar? In other words, are you switching between three views using the tab bar and all you want is to have another view that can appear modally on top of any of the three?

Comment: I would like a mix of three : I have a tab bar, whom each child view could present controllers and I want to know the best way to display a view on top of all the others view whenever I want.

Comment: The most straightforward way is to present a controller modally, as necessary, from your current navigation controller. Instead of presenting from the `UITabBarController` which gave you a conflict, have the modal presentation be made by a `UINavigationController`.